# Zend app using sass/compass generated css

Tags: zend-framework, sass, compass-sass

I am generating css "bundles" from sass/compass for usage in a Zend app.

In my dev environment I want to have the bundles contain all the comments back to the original sass files to track down visual bugs.

In production I want to minify, compress, and send them to a cdn with a unique md5 name generated from the scss versions as part of a deploy process.

What is a good way for Zend to manage which url to use in which environment?  Is a view helper  a good solution?  Is there a better way?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could write your own `Zend_Application_Resource` (e.g. based on the existing `Zend_Application_Resource_View`), just add the css-settings to your application.ini and then simply call the urlHelper in your layout/view.

An even simpler approach would be to just conditionally set the viewHelper in your layout based on your APPLICATION_ENV.

A more elaborate approach would be to integrate [Assetic](https://github.com/kriswallsmith/assetic) in your app.

Comment: What advantages does Assetic give me?

Comment: Essentially it's an asset-manager for css- and js-resources, including various filters such as a Sass-Filter. I am not sure whether it supports the full range of what you want to do in production, but minifying, compression and sass-filter are available. In development you could run it with the debug-flag enabled which should produce what you want. I played around with it a bit, but haven't yet used it somewhere productively, so I can't say for sure if it really fits your needs.

Comment: Assetic looks cool, but there are features in compass like sprite building that I think we want. Your first suggestion look good, I think I will write a custom app resource view and on the production side populate an ini file with my build script that runs compass.  Thanks!